# Brute Forcing a aspx form using Hydra

Tags: javascript, web, hydra

I am trying to brute force a Login.aspx page. 
It has two text fields - txt_Username and txt_Password
The form submit however looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="btn_Login" value="Login" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;btn_Login&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="btn_Login" class="btn btn-success">
```

On wrong login, there is a popup which shows the message Wrong User Name or Password.
I have a correct username and password for testing. I put that, along with few wrong passwords in mostcommon.txt file. 
I ran the below command:

```
.\hydra -V -l 10026 -P mostcommon.txt -o
found.txt xxx.yyy http-post-form “/Login.aspx:txt_Username=^USER^&txt_Password=^PASS^:Wrong"
```

However, I get all 5 passwords as valid. What am I doing wrong?
Any help would be much appreciated.